# How to pass array as a value in constructor in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor

I want to assign values directly to the marks array in the constructor Student. I want to pass the value as

```
Student s1 = new Student(123,"jack sparrow",3, {23.0,40.0,30.0});
```

is it possible?

```
error illegal start of expression.
error illegal start of type
```